# Approach for Text mining on a file and assigning category

Tags: nlp, rstudio

Need help in deciding an algorithmic approach where the text is read line by line the text contains description of incident ticket, one reading each row it should assign a category to that incident type using a set of keywords association already decided ...for example if the description contain words like password(s) then it should assign it as a category password issue. 
Kindly help

Comment: You might want to edit your question and add information regarding what you have tried already to solve the problem. If you don't, you run the risk of question getting downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try bag-of-words, or document vectors.

If there are spelling errors, you’ll need fuzzymatching techniques.

You’ll want to clean stop words beforehand as well.

Good luck.